# Remove association from Rails 5 self join table without deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a self join table on my `product` model using a model called `matches` as the join table.  What I would like to do is when deleting a product to have the associated product removed but not deleted.  Right now I am trying `dependent:  :destroy` which doesn't work, but I know its not what I want because I don't want to delete the self associated product.

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :variations, -> { order(:order) }, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_many :matches
  has_many :matched_products, through: :matches, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

**match.rb**

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :matched_product, class_name: 'Product', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :variations, :through => :matched_product
end
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the `dependent: :destroy` on `:matches` instead of on `:matched_products`?

Comment: I did.  This is the error I get `PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "products" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_b784169452" on table "matches" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "matches". : DELETE FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1`

Comment: I suspect you get that error because you are trying to delete a `product` that is a `matched_product` from some other `product`. (In other words, a record in the `matches` table has has the `id` from the product you are deleting in the `matched_product_id` column.) Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: You might try adding something like `has_many :product_matches, class_name: 'Match', foreign_key: :matched_product_id, dependent: :destroy` to `Product`. Also, it seems like you probably don't want `dependent: :destroy` for `belongs_to :matched_product, class_name: 'Product'` in `Match`.

Comment: Brilliant!  This worked great!

Comment: Added answer for future searchers. Feel free to upvote/accept as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you update your models as follows:

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :variations, -> { order(:order) }, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_many :matches, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :product_matches, class_name: 'Match', foreign_key: :matched_product_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :matched_products, through: :matches
  ...
end
```

This will ensure that all `matches` records are deleted when deleting a `product` whether the `product` is a `product` or `matched_product` in the `match` record. Removing `dependent: :destroy` from `has_many :matched_products` will prevent deletion of the, well, `matched_products`.

**match.rb**

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :matched_product, class_name: 'Product'
  has_many :variations, :through => :matched_product
end
```

Similar to above, removing `dependent: :destroy` from `belongs_to :matched_product, class_name: 'Product'` will prevent deletion of the `matched_product`.